# How to use GMSPlacePickerViewController class?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places

I created the picker as follows:

```
let placePicker = GSMPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

placePicker.delegate?.placePicker(viewController: GSMPlacePickerViewController, didPick: GSMPlace)
```

In the second line of the code above, how can I store the place the user picks inside a variable of my own so later I can access its [properties](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) like the coordinates?

I am confused on how to implement `GSMPlacePickerViewController` method and couldn't find examples online.

As from the `GSMPlacePickerViewController` [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_place_picker_view_controller_delegate-p), it says that I don't have to implement the first parameter and I could leave it empty if I understood it correctly

> Implementations of this method should dismiss the view controller as
>   the view controller will not dismiss itself.

So my problem now, is storing the user selected location in a variable of my own.

How should I go to achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate** to your view controller like so:

```
class YourViewController: GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate {

}
```

Then add the delegate method within said VC which will be called when the user picks the place. You then dismiss and access place data like below:

```
 func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
                placePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
}
```